# reactjs: chrome browser console log: unable to locate the error location of which line and file

Tags: reactjs

While running my reactjs application i can see an warning in my console as below. But unfortunately i am not able to understand where the error is coming from and how to rectify this.

[image]

Comment: I would try searching the entire project for `outlined`. The error is saying that it expected `outlined` to be a string but right now it's a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser console error outlines file, line and column number that caused the exception. Your stack trace says that the exception is raised in `bundle.js` at line 20893, column 66. You should be able to click the link and open the file in the Chrome Dev tools *Sources* tab. However, `bundle.js` is the JavaScript file generated from your build process (you are probably using Webpack, Vite or some other budnler) and it's not very debug friendly. The best way to debug errors is by using Source Maps. Source Maps are files that map the bundled and transpiled JavaScript to your source code. If you distribute them them along with the production build files, Chrome Dev Tools are able to map the error directly in your source files, not in the bundled one. You can read more at the following resources:

- https://web.dev/source-maps/
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/ (if you are using Webpack)

Comment: i am using `npm start` and it indirectly runs ` "start": "react-scripts start",`. Why its building as `build.js`

Comment: `react-scripts` uses Webpack under the hood which bundles all your source files in a single `bundle.js`.

Comment: then how can i see the sources files as it is while developing reactjs project. without creating bundle.js